# How to test hoc stateful component with React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-hooks

I have a Layout hoc component and I wanna guarantee the state changes.
Here my Layout component:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

import styles from './Layout.module.css'
import Toolbar from '../../components/UI/Navigation/Toolbar/Toolbar'
import SideDrawer from '../../components/UI/Navigation/SideDrawer/SideDrawer'

const Layout = (props) => {

    const [sideDrawerIsVisible, setSideDrawerIsVisible] = useState(false)

    const sideDrawerClosedHandler = () => {
        setSideDrawerIsVisible(false)
    }

    const slideDrawerToggleHandler = () => {
        setSideDrawerIsVisible((prevState) => !prevState)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Toolbar
                height="2em"
                drawerToggleClicked={slideDrawerToggleHandler} />
            <SideDrawer
                open={sideDrawerIsVisible}
                closed={sideDrawerClosedHandler} />
            <main className={styles.Content}>
                {props.children}
            </main>
        </>
    );
}

export default Layout
```

The solution that I found is received the instance and use the `useState()`.

I need the instance to set the state and verify it after the click action. The test in hand is `should update state when drawer toggle clicked` but according to the Enzyme documentation to "stateless" components we receive null to `instance()` but this changed in React Hooks. There is a better approach to test this situation?

```js
import React from 'react';

import { configure, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

import Layout from './Layout';
import Toolbar from '../../components/UI/Navigation/Toolbar/Toolbar';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('<Layout />', () => {
    let wrapper;

    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = shallow(<Layout>children...</Layout>);
    });

    it('should update state when drawer toggle clicked', () => {
        const toolbar = wrapper.find(Toolbar);
        wrapper.instance().setSideDrawerIsVisible(true);
        toolbar.props().drawerToggleClicked();
        expect(wrapper.sideDrawerIsVisible).toEqual(false);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't try to init state through workaround ways. Interact with component through its public interface - I mean props.

```
it('displays drawer after toolbar is clicked', () => {
    const toolbar = wrapper.find(Toolbar);
    toolbar.props().drawerToggleClicked();
    expect(wrapper.find(SideDrawer).props().open).toEqual(true);
});

it('hides drawer after toolbar is clicked for second time', () => {
    const toolbar = wrapper.find(Toolbar);
    toolbar.props().drawerToggleClicked();
    toolbar.props().drawerToggleClicked();
    expect(wrapper.find(SideDrawer).props().open).toEqual(false);
});

it('hides drawer initially shown after closing it from inside', () => {
    const toolbar = wrapper.find(Toolbar);
    toolbar.props().drawerToggleClicked(); // to display drawer
    const sideDrawer = wrapper.find(SideDrawer);
    sideDrawer.props().closed();
    expect(sideDrawer.props().open).toEqual(false);
});
```

when you operate on `instance()` directly or use Enzyme's `setState()` you are bounding your tests to component's internals and tests become fragile with no advantages.